# optimizing a sql select nested where query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Since I am a beginner i need to know one thing.
I am having a query in php like this..what is the best performance implementation of this query:

```
    select Sub_Code,Sub_Name from subj_mast where Dept_id=
       (select Dep_Id from academic where Reg_No=$reg)
       and Sem='$sem' and (Sub_Type='core' or subj_mast.Sub_Code=
(select Elective_code from elective where Reg_No=$reg and Sem='$sem'))
        or subj_mast.Sub_Code
      (select Sub_Code from history_of_arrear where Reg_No=$reg)
```

Actually this query works well but i think this makes the retrieval slow..
Help me with this...

Comment: I don't think knowing one thing will be enough.

Comment: This could probably be solved with simple JOINs : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Could you actually just show us the SQL, rather than the string you're generating in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after a bit of re-arranging I cleaned up and structured the SQL as best I could I got this:

```
SELECT
    Sub_Code,
    Sub_Name
FROM subj_mast
WHERE
    Dept_id = (
        SELECT
            Dep_Id
        FROM academic
        WHERE
            Reg_No=$reg
    )
    AND
    Sem='$sem'
    AND (
        Sub_Type='core'
        OR
        subj_mast.Sub_Code=(
            SELECT
                Elective_code
            FROM elective
            WHERE
                Reg_No=$reg
                AND
                Sem='$sem'
        )
    )
    OR
    subj_mast.Sub_Code = (
        SELECT
            Sub_Code
        FROM history_of_arrear
        WHERE
            Reg_No=$reg
    )
```

After moving the subqueries into joins, and optimising them as best I can without access to a test copy of the database and data this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
    S.Sub_Code,
    S.Sub_Name
FROM subj_mast S
LEFT JOIN academic A
  ON A.Dep_id = S.Dept_Id

LEFT JOIN history_of_arrear H
  ON H.Sub_Code = S.Sub_Code
     AND
     H.Reg_No=A.Reg_No

LEFT JOIN Elective_code E
  ON E.Sub_Code = S.Sub_Code
     AND
     E.Reg_No=$reg
     AND
     E.Sem='$sem'

WHERE
    S.Sem='$sem'
    AND
    A.Reg_No=$reg
    AND (
        S.Sub_Type='core'
        OR
        E.Sub_Code IS NOT NULL
    )
    OR
    H.Sub_Code IS NOT NULL
```

You should create the following indices:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_subjMas_dept_sem ON subj_mast(Dept_Id, Sem);
CREATE INDEX idx_academic_dep_regNo ON academic(Dep_id, Reg_No);
CREATE INDEX idx_historyOfArrear_subCode_regNo ON history_of_arrear(Sub_Code, Reg_No);
CREATE INDEX idx_ElectiveCode_sem_subCode_regNo ON history_of_arrear(Sem, Sub_Code, Reg_No);
```

Which should assist MySQL in making these joins.

Comment: thanks a lot really you helped me a lot...But actually i dont know the concept of indexing thanks i will learn it quickly

Comment: @scragar: note the precedence of `AND` and `OR`, your statement _differs_ from the original. If the predicate after the last `OR` in OP query is TRUE, none of the other predicates matter. Your query appears to relocate that `OR` under an `AND`, which is _not_ the same as the original query. (This could well be what OP intended, but it's not equivalent to original query.)

Comment: @spencer7593 The query he posted had an uneven number of opening/closing brackets, I did the best I could with what I had, and even made sure it was obvious what I was working from by posting my re-organised copy of his query at the top to show what I was working from. If it's a wrong assumption on where the closing bracket goes I welcome him to explain where and I'll fix it, until then this is a best guess.

Comment: @user3496195 Indices are actually a pretty simply concept, just imagine them as a table of contents or glossary for a book, when you want to look up something you don't look at every page, you look at the table of contents or glossary to see where it appears in the book, then look at just the pages that are relevant. For MySQL this is an index, when you search for something if the where clause is index'd it'll use the index to work out what rows to look at, rather than checking every row.

Comment: @scragar: The original post had two closing parens on the line before the last OR. A paren disappeared on the edit, when the SQL got moved out of the PHP code. (Question is already closed, so I can't post what I have as an answer.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Ah, I see that now. Edited.